# node.js with knex - when commit is done (mysql db)

Tags: node.js, knex.js

Probably this is dummy question, but when I am running multiple `insert / update knex` queries one after another (including asyncrhonouse Promise like) during one connection without using some additional transactions - commit is done after each `insert/update` query?

Comment: To group multiple updates together as a single transaction at the Knex level, see http://knexjs.org/#Transactions . Otherwise they will be handled as @Mikael notes below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

tldr; Yes.

Depends on your mysql db configuration (see. autocommit https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-autocommit-commit-rollback.html). Anyways it is set on by default and in that case commit is done after every insert / update operation (when not using transactions).